# Work with huge file in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, file

I have big sql file, i need to change some lines there, now i have such data in my file

```
 INSERT INTO `LINK_LA_TYP` VALUES
 ('1','8917181','1','24','2'),
 ('1','8934610','1','24','1'),
 ('1','9403766','1','30','1'),
 ('1','9422299','1','30','2'),
```

I done that, for example on $count line i write one more

> INSERT INTO `LINK_LA_TYP` VALUES

but then my file looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `LINK_LA_TYP` VALUES
 ('1','8917181','1','24','2'),
 ('1','8934610','1','24','1'),
 ('1','9403766','1','30','1'),
 INSERT INTO `LINK_LA_TYP` VALUES
 ('1','9422299','1','30','2'),
```

But i need that previous line symbol , change to ; How i can do this in big file? 
So i need to see file and write there line(done) and then change , to ; on previous line, and do this on every ~500 line (depends on counter) to the end of file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest workflow:

Create a temporary file. Then:

- Read one line at a time from the original file
- Do your work on that line
- Write the changed line to the temporary file
- Repeat.

When you are done, simply rename the temp file to the correct filename, which will remove the old file.

---

*If* each line are going to be *the exact same size as before*, you may instead change the file inline. You can do this by aligning the file pointer correctly with [fseek](http://php.net/fseek) and then writing. This is a little bit trickier to achieve but may save you the space for the temp file (and possibly be a little bit faster as well). This is only possible if the resulting file size will be exactly the same as the original file size (e.g., if you only change certain bytes from one character to another).

Answer (score 0):

If you read in the file stream (for example via [`fgets`](http://php.net/fgets); see example there), you should count the lines and replace the comma with a semicolon on line X; and insert a new line at X + 1. No need to get a previous line.

Answer (score 0):

Took some time to mock this together.

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/,\n INSERT INTO/;\n INSERT INTO/g' your_file.sql
```

You can put this in exec() if you really want to run it from php script.